# strange "urlencoded" and "multipart/form-data" content when using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, forms

I have the following jQuery script:

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var mydata = "öäüöäü";
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:10000",
    type: "POST",
    data : mydata,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    })
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to parse request with Python, what I see on the wire if I run the code above is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: localhost:10000\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n
Referer: http://localhost/index_ajax.html\r\n
Content-Length: 12\r\n
Origin: http://localhost\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
\r\n
\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc
```

Content-Type is "x-www-form-urlencoded" but all the data seems to be byte-encoded
and not percent encoded as defined for this content type.

Changing ajax code from:

```
data : mydata,
```

to

```
{'mydata': data}
```

produces same headers and correct body content:

```
mydata=%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC
```

The content is now as expected percent-encoded.

Same body is produced if I add to ajax code another content-type:

```
contentType:"multipart/form-data"
```

now I see "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8" in headers, but the body itself
isn't just as expected for multipart/form-data.

Why does jQuery allow sending non-conform data to server? How do I send correct data to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type header you see is the default header to be sent. When you set `data` to a *string*, jQuery assumes you have taken care of the encoding yourself, for any conversion to take place (e.g. the form URL encoding) you *have* to send an object.

See the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **contentType** (default: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)

and

> **data**
>   Type: `PlainObject` or `String` or `Array`
>   Data to be sent to the server. **It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.**

Emphasis mine.

If jQuery converted strings, you'd never be able to send valid content types that should *not* be URL-encoded, like a JSON or XML post body, nor could you post data that was already URL-encoded by other means.

To manually encode data yourself, use the [`encodeURIComponent()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:10000",
    type: "POST",
    data : encodeURIComponent(mydata),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    })
});
```